# jquery.val() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason, probably an obvious one, jquery.val() is returning undefined. Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
<input class=".start" id="Project_StartDate" name="Project.StartDate" value="6.9.2013 0:00:00" type="hidden"/>

$(".start").val() <---- Returns undefined
```

Better example: http://jsfiddle.net/DvfxF/16/

Comment: `<input class="start" id="Project_StartDate" name="Project.StartDate" value="6.9.2013 0:00:00" type="hidden"/>` remove the `dot`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your class is wrong, change:

```
<input class=".start" ...
```

to

```
<input class="start" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not use . in class attribute buddy,
change your code to this one:

```
<input class="start" id="Project_StartDate" name="Project.StartDate" value="6.9.2013 0:00:00" type="hidden"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You class name is wrong. Change `class=".start"` to `class="start"`.
We are referring to the class by putting . before the class name in jQuery. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DvfxF/21/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.` from the class in markup.

```
<input class="start" id="Project_StartDate" name="Project.StartDate" value="6.9.2013 0:00:00" type="hidden"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.` in the class name of `class=".start"`

http://jsfiddle.net/DvfxF/17/